# Remove filename and timestamp from git-blame

Tags: git, git-blame

Long filepaths and unneeded timestamps are making it hard for me to read the output of `git blame`.  I'd like to remove these columns from the output, but keep the SHA, line number, and author name.

I see in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) that the `-f` or `--show-filename` flags *include* the filename (even though it's included by default), but there doesn't appear to be a flag for *removing* the filename.  I often use `git blame` on a single file, so I already know which file I'm looking at.

I also see a flag for suppressing both the author name and timestamp (`-s`), but I'd prefer to keep the author name, so this flag won't work for what I need.

I even tried to combine the `-s` flag with the `-e` flag (to use the author's email instead of their name), but that trick failed to output anything for the author.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no such option, one could use `sed`:

```
git blame --date=short <filename> | sed -e 's, [^(]*, ,' -e 's, [^ ]*\( *[0-9]*)\), \1,'
```

The first regex will need tiny adjustment if you have parentheses in the filenames. (hopefully you don't) It will work correctly even without filenames.

Comment: You can get shorter than that, use `--date=short` on the blame to reduce the date to a single field, then your sed's `sed -e 's, [^(]*, ,' -e 's, [^ ]* \([0-9]*)\), \1,'` which strips any filename that doesn't have parens and the short date.

Comment: thanks @jthill, adjusted the answer per your comment.

Comment: This works great.  I wrapped it in a bash function named `gitb`, which I stashed in my .bash_profile.  I replaced `<filename>` with the `$1` argument and now I can do things like `gitb Gemfile` and the output looks exactly how I want it to look.  Cheers.

Comment: @RichieThomas I made a small fix is the regexp. The error was the variable number of spaces in before the line number broke removing the date.